# ReactJS Top Margin

Tags: css, reactjs

Exploring ReactJS and I cannot seem to get rid of the top margin on the page.  I have included the css file in the index.js module:
index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Panel from "./panel/panel";
import "./index.css" ;
ReactDOM.render(
    <Panel>Will Build A Form In Here!</Panel>,document.getElementById("root")
);
```

index.css

```
.wrapper, body, html{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  background-color: rgb(25,48,72) !important;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <title>React Router Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root" class="wrapper"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Oddly enough, when I examined the page in the developer console for Chromium, the page had a bunch of `&nbsp` peppered, whcih was causing the space at the top.

[image]

Is there anyway to fix this so I have no margins or padding on the body?

Comment: It looks like the `&nbsp` are likely coming from the Panel component, can you please include the contents of that file in the question?

Comment: It looks like you have two different kinds of spaces in your html document since these are outside of the `#root` element. Did you copy paste the html document? try running a formatter on it

Comment: It looks like `<meta>` and `<link>` tags are also being rendered to the `body` element when they shouldn't.

Comment: @NathanFries That's has to be the oddest thing I have ever seen.  Formatted the HTML and it works now.  Post as answer so I can give you cred.  Thanks All!!

Comment: That was my point actually haha, but usually its when copy pasting a HTML document template from a website with a different encoding. Spaces are treated differently

Comment: Ah, @JohnRuddell, my apologies. Your suggestion worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: All good my friend! :)